# SOLVED - How to set up X2Go on Raspeberry Pi Zero 2 W?

Tags: remote, desktop

I do prefer the x2Goserver and not the RealVNC that comes with the RasPI and I'd like to know if there's a working solution for the Zero 2 W. I've tried it many times and it just seems that it doesn't work. Can't connect. I get an authentication error. I have the latest Raspberry OS Bullseye.

##### Is there a working solution for this? Thanks :)

##### I'm a noob in the Pi area as of now. Not with Linux though.

Comment: `it just seems that it doesn't work`. Can you clarify that? What did you try|? Any error messages? Please add more detail to your question.

Comment: Well, I've installed the `x2gosever` packages needed to run a server on my RPI and I could not connect to it. On the client app It would give me an authentication error and that's about it. I didn't know how to go deeper and troubleshoot this. And for now SSH was enough but I'm installing KaliLinux right now and I will set up the x2go server again. I will be back with details of the process and hopefully a working solution, this should be a piece of cake process. This might help: https://vid.puffyan.us/watch?v=Qzjg8MvdkmA

Answer (score 0):

###### Indeed the solution was in front of me. I just didn't look close enough.

I've only had to use the default port for ssh i.e. `22`, cause previously I was using another port. I'm sure this wasn't working the first time because x2go by default uses this port and I didn't change that in the `x2go` config file to what I was actually using for SSH.

##### SOLUTION

So just by installing `x2goserver` with `apt install x2goserver` on the PI and then connecting from the client app with the right credentials made it work.

##### DRAWBACKS

Realistically speaking the remote desktop it's not usable. What was I thinking?! It's 512 RAM afterall. RealVNC would work better.
The processor is spiking up and it just can't handle the laod, as well as the RAM. But it's doable.

###### This is how it looks anyways:

[image: Image1]
Couldn't even start the termianl cause it all just froze.